# Racket "match" construct - is it a macro?

Tags: macros, pattern-matching, racket

Simple question - is the `match` form in Racket a macro? It certainly seems like it could be defined as a macro, but I thought it might be baked further into the implementation to make it faster or something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2578) if you're curious about how it's implemented. In general, all of the syntactic forms that are not listed on [this page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#(part._fully-expanded)) in the docs are built as macros.

Answer (score 0):

`match` is not a macro. It is a regular Racket function.

EDIT:
I was totally wrong. Match is a macro. Here's the documentation. http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html

Comment: ... how? It binds new variables, and uses syntax which doesn't have any meaning outside of macros (e.g. ellipses). Also, the bodies of the match clauses are only executed conditionally, if the pattern of that clause matches. How can this be done with a function?

Comment: You're right, I was totally wrong. See the link to the documentation above.